# Netsuite Custom field to add days to date of other field based on which is filled

Tags: netsuite, case-statement

I have been trying to create a column field in Netsuite to add days to a date based on which field is populated.

I have come accross CASE statements which I thought would do it but I cant seem to get it to work.

This is what I have so far

```
case when 
{custcol_fob_date} and {custcol_stock_ready_date}is null then
{shipdate}+40 else
{custcol_stock_ready_date}is null then
{custcol_fob_date}+30 else
{custcol_fob_date} is null then
{custcol_stock_ready_date}+35
END
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your case statement:

1. You need a condition to test before `and` - I think what you mean is `{custcol_fob_date} is null and {custcol_stock_ready_date} is null`.  Without the first `is null` or some other test to compare `{custcol_fob_date}` with, the expression is invalid.
2. You are missing `when` after `else` in two places.  The only time `else` should appear without `when` is for a catch-all at the end of the statement, and then it should be used without a condition to test.

Try the following (slightly revised from your code):

```
case when 
{custcol_fob_date} IS NULL and {custcol_stock_ready_date} is null then
{shipdate}+40 else WHEN
{custcol_stock_ready_date} is null then
{custcol_fob_date}+30 else WHEN
{custcol_fob_date} is null then
{custcol_stock_ready_date}+35
END
```

This does not have a catch-all at the end, so if none of the conditions are met, there will be no value set.

ALSO NOTE: You must set the field to dynamic (uncheck the 'Store Value' box) for this to work.