# How to add 180 days to trandate in suiteflow on event of afterSubmit?

Tags: sql, date, workflow, netsuite

I need to set a custom date field with the value of trandate + 180 days. for example, if trandate is 21/03/2019 then the custom field value should set as 17/09/2019.
I tried doing the simple way `{trandate}+180` but NaN is being shown as field value.
I found one field formula `ADD_MONTHS(date, integer)` but this is for adding months, while client requires is a date exact 180 days ahead of the transaction date.
Can anyone help me in doing that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: its an ERP, Oracle Netsuite. They have their own DB.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48811814/7032856) may help.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using {trandate} then what you have written should work in a formuladate context so first thing is check your syntax.

Sometimes though Netsuite returns everything as strings so the next thing to try is `TO_DATE({trandate}) + 180`

Comment: Thank U bknights!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about with SuiteFlow, but maybe this will help.

- If you are using SuiteScript 1.0

  - var tranDate=nlapiStringToDate(trandate);
  - var newTranDate=nlapiAddDays(tranDate,180);
- If you are using SuiteScript 2.0

  - var tranDate=new Date(trandate);
  - var newTranDate=tranDate.setDate(tranDate.getDate()+180);